# define which fields to search from admin panel in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

In my wordpress site, when i use the search it searches all the fields of the post.
I am looking for a way to define which fields it will look for *from the default search of wordpress*.

there are many manuals on creating your own custom search, but i am looking to make changes from dashboard or from search.php

any suggestions?

Comment: You want to restrict the wordpress search in to search limited posts or custom posts ?

Comment: @MoeedFarooqui hi, i want to restrict to search custom posts but search the default fields. i think i saw somewhere checkboxes in which you specify the fields but i am not sure it was it (in the dashboard)

Answer (score 2):

Here is the example :

```
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>">
        <input type="text" name="s" id="s" value="Enter keywords ..." onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;"/><br />
        <select name="post_type">
            <option value="">Choose Category:</option>
            <option value="">All Categories</option>
            <option value="post_type_a">Post Type A</option>
            <option value="post_type_b">Post Type B</option>
             <option value="post_type_c">Post Type C</option>
        </select><br />
        <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search Help" />
    </form>
```

If you dont want to show the `custom post types` in drop down you can assign the values in hiden fields also, something like below.

```
<input type="hidden" name="post_type[]" value="post_type_one" />
<input type="hidden" name="post_type[]" value="post_type_two" />
<input type="hidden" name="post_type[]" value="post_type_three" />
```

Comment: thank you but its not quite what i was looking for,can you tell me where is the query for the input? i mean where is the input computed?

Comment: hey man i am sorry but i figured it out already, i was looking for the place where the input is beeing processed. found it in query.php

Comment: ahan so was my answer helpfull ?